# Ubuntu Partition Not Showing in Installer

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation

Ubuntu installer doesn't show partitions when installing. Did Everything Possible From Bios. And I Created a Partition.

Comment: Then what does it show?

Comment: Please provide more details. More on how to ask a good question so more people can answer your question:https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What brand model system? What drive? Have you updated UEFI firmware and if SSD, updated SSD firmware? Is Windows fast start up or bitlocker on?